# Processing Multithread socket connection in java

Tags: java, multithreading, io, thread-safety

I have a server and a client. Server is capable of handling multiple request. Client opens a socket and sends a stream of bytes. While the server is processing, it is not behaving correctly. From the client I am sending the following lines

ADD this as your client

Title: Client1

for 5 different clients

I am using the string builder to build the formatted string as above.

```
 for (i=0; i<6; i++)
 {
     Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append("ADD this as your client ");
                    sb.append("\r\n");
                    sb.append("Title: Client");
                    sb.append(i);
                    sb.append("\r\n");
                    String ToSend = sb.toString();


                    /// New Additions
                    byte[] byteArray = ToSend.getBytes();
                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    dos.writeInt(byteArray.length);
                    dos.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
                    socket.close();
                   }
```

In the server I am reading this like this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sampleserver file_rec = new Sampleserver();
   try {
  ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);

  while (true) {
    file_rec.socket = listener.accept();  
    new Thread(file_rec).start();
  }
}
catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}

}
public void run() {
try {
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    int length = dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("Length value is " + length);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[length];


   int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, length);

    String s = new String(mybytearray, 0, length);
    System.out.println(s);
    if (s.contains("ADD"))
    {
        System.out.println("Inside ADD. ");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Default ");
    }

 }

catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

}

But everytime in the server I am getting weird output. I think I am not handling either the bytearray properly or handling it wrongly in the server while processing it in threaded environment (in the run method). Can you please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: you should also show us the code where you actually open the sockets

Comment: similar requirement in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Comment: jeff.. I have added the code..

Comment: close `dos` before you close the socket. What does does the weird output look like?

Comment: Sometimes i get the following exception.. java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
 at .run(IP_Project_Server.java:67)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: I have edited the code.. Kindly check for the updated once. Everytime I am opening the socket and closing it after sending the byte in the loop..

Comment: Zapl.. I did that.. It is of no sure :(

Comment: you get `bytesRead` and don't use it. Why?